# Does Indonesia require some sort of mandatory quarantine in a facility upon arrival?

Tags: covid-19, indonesia, quarantine

I have finally managed to get a visa to visit Indonesia, which has closed all borders except for citizens.
However, I can't find concrete information on the quarantine part.

Does Indonesia require some sort of quarantine in a facility? I have read that somewhere a while ago now I can't find it. I am ok with self-quarantine as I have a house there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Indonesia require some sort of mandatory quarantine in a facility upon arrival?

14-day self-quarantine at home unless your covid test is positive, in which case you're likely to end up in a facility.

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> Indonesia:

> 3. Passengers without a printed medical certificate in English with a negative Coronavirus (COVID-19) PCR test result issued at most 7 days before arrival are subject to medical screening and quarantine for 14 days.

https://id.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/covid-19-information/:

> - Are U.S. citizens required to quarantine? Yes
> - All foreign visitors arriving in Indonesia are required to:
>
>   - Hold a health certificate issued by health authorities from their home countries
>   - Undertake a mandatory 14-day quarantine at designated facilities conducted by the Indonesian government or self-quarantine under
>     supervision of the Indonesian health authority
>   - If you cannot obtain a COVID test prior to traveling to Indonesia, the government will test you upon arrival at the airport. You must
>     agree to be quarantined if you test positive.
>
> If you have questions about this policy, we will refer you to the
> government of Indonesia through one of its consulates or its embassy
> in the United States.
> https://kemlu.go.id/washington/en/news/6762/important-updates-requirements-to-enter-indonesia.

https://kemlu.go.id/washington/en/news/6762/important-updates-requirements-to-enter-indonesia:

[image]